# Arraylist is one element longer than intended

Tags: java, arraylist, element

I want to create an Arraylist that holds strings as the user inputs them:

```
System.out.println("How many words do you want to enter?");
int numVerbs = scan.nextInt();
ArrayList <String> verbs = new ArrayList <String> (numVerbs);
System.out.println("Start entering words:");
for(int i=0;i<=numVerbs;i++){
   verbs.add(scan.nextLine());
}
System.out.print(verbs.size());
}
```

The problem is that when I create and add the strings to the list, and then print out the size of the arraylist, it's one element larger than I want it to be.

For example, I'll enter 3 as how many words I want to add, then I'll input 3 words. However, when I print back the size of the arraylist it's 4 - not 3.

Maybe it has something to do with the verbs.add to an empty list? Idk, I'm at a loss.

Comment: i  <=, array list gets recreated with more capacity, change <= to <, you are starting from 0.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use a debugger. This is an invaluable tool for anyone learning to write computer programs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @GCP your explanation is kind of missleading. While the `<=` in this particular case is the cause of the resize, `ArrayList`s do in general always resize when they reached their capacity (I am quite sure that you are well aware of this, just wanted to clarify for future readers).

Comment: @Turing85 I just put it out there because he is explicitly assigning capacity to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start the loop at `1`:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= numVerbs; i++){ ... }
```

or change the condition from `i <= numVerbs` to `i < numVerbs`

```
for(int i = 0; i < numVerbs; i++){ ... }
```

This is necessary because as is, the for loop is starting at `0` and then looping until the number entered *inclusive* hence you're performing one extra iteration than required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That fixed the size of the arraylist, but now I can only input 2 words when it outputs a size of 3. Is there a way to input 3 words into the array list and have it also output the size as 3?

Comment: @MajorMoo insert a `scan.nextLine();` call before the for loop to consume the last newline character of your input. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo) for more explanation as to why it's required.

Comment: Ooooohhh - yeah that fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace for:each loop with `while scan.hasNextLine()` as well, provided you don't need to ask user the number of words upfront.